# Server seems alive - but won't run any commands

Tags: linux, ubuntu, freeze

I recognise that I will probably have no choice but to force reset the server in question, but I wonder if anyone can offer any insight as to why this is happening.

I can ssh into my Virtual Private Server just fine.

```
Linux oliland 2.6.27-xenU-4265-i386 #2 SMP Thu Dec 9 09:23:05 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux
Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS

Welcome to Ubuntu!
 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
Last login: Wed Oct  5 19:13:30 2011 from herp.derp.com
```

I can even resume my tmux session!

```
$ tmux a -d
```

I notice my weechat client seems to have frozen. Not to worry, I'll kill it from another tmux window. Time to find that process ID.

```
$ ps aux
■
```

Weird, it's printing nothing. Perhaps the problem is in tmux. I'll detach and try some other commands.

```
$ ls
■
```

Nothing at all? What's going on? Well it printed some things when I logged in, so some things must work...

```
$ uname
Linux
```

Odd.

Comment: It does sound like your VPS is locked up sort of. I would request a reset to your host and see if that helps out.

Answer (score 1):

Try blind-typing "reset" and "stty sane". It is possible that the commands are in fact returning data but the terminal settings are such that it isn't displayed.